# Returning results from two different SQL tables as search results

Tags: java, sql

I have two different tables containing similar data but slightly different format.

Is it possible to return search results from both tables?  I also need to paginate these results.

Comment: use a SQL "join" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29, or a "union" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator to retrieve data from both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to query both tables and return results in just one query:

```
SELECT field1,field2  FROM table1
UNION
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table2
```

If `table1` and `table2` are very different you can combine the `UNION` with a more complex `FROM` using another `select` something like ...

```
SELECT field1,field2  FROM (SELECT id1 as field1,id2 as field2 FROM table1a,table1b WHERE id1 = id2)
UNION
SELECT field1,field2 FROM table2
```

To paginate results you can enclose a union in another `select` and use `limit` and `offset` ....

```
SELECT field1,field2 FROM (
    SELECT field1,field2  FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT field1,field2 FROM table2
) LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

If you give us a small description of the tables structure we might be able to help better.